# How to import a nltk.corpus by using a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, python-import, corpus

so I am trying to receive input to which corpus we want to access in this problem.  As shown below I have the input set to be 'corp'.

The problem is when I run my program, the computer says it can't find the corpus 'corp' instead of actually using the 'corp' term as the variable it is.  Any idea how to take an input and use it as a variable in the phrase 'from nltk.corpus import XXX'

Thanks in advance! :)

```
def chi_square(w1, w2, corp):
    from nltk.corpus import corp
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use a dictionary to keep the corpus object instead.

Comment: Because nltk corpus are lazily evaluated, the full object won't be materialize until you run a function from the corpus, so you can actually import all the corpora you need and then use a dictionary to hold the names as the keys and the actual corpora as the values

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk.corpus as corp
```

This is a way how you import a python package using your own custom name.

Comment: Wouldn't that just hold the process of 'import.corpus' within corp, instead of using the content that is already stored in 'corp'?